# Is it possible to get an SSL certificate for a portforwarding VPN service?

Tags: ssl-certificate, vpn, portforwarding

In my example I am using https://portmap.io VPN service which is not exactly a pure VPN services but still uses VPN technology to break my ISP restrictions, allowing portforwarding to my own home server running in my android device.

So if I run 193.161.193.99:1200, my website gets browsed. The port 1200 is mapped to my local python server port running on port 1000. Port 1200 is given by the VPN provider.

However, if I try 193.161.193.99 without the port 1200. The portmap VPN official website gets called, cause that's the websites' IP. So basically each user of this VPN services has there own port to work with.

**Question**: I don't have any public IP  totally in my own control to get an SSL certificate, which requires a file upload verification by the CA (CSR). So, it it anyhow possible to get an SSL certificate using 193.161.193.99:1200 ?

> Note: Services like zerossl.com accepts to provide a certificate for ipv4 public addresses. So it not always essential to use a FQDN to get a cert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you will need a domain pointing to the VPN/portmap IP and then obtain a SLL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for that domain. This can be your own domain or one provided by a Dynamic DNS Service such as [Duck DNS](https://www.duckdns.org/).

I'll describe how I have done it with Docker and Duck DNS in detail:

1. Sign in to Duck DNS, create a subdomain and point it to the VPN/portmap IP, note the token at the top of the page.
2. Deploy a docker container from LinuxServer.io's [SWAG Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag)
3. Make sure to provide the required environment variables in your docker-compose.yml (or with docker run command):

```
- VALIDATION=duckdns
- DUCKDNSTOKEN={your token}
- URL={yourdomain}.duckdns.org
```

*Note: If you want everything behind your VPN, there is a great docker container called [gluetun](https://hub.docker.com/r/qmcgaw/gluetun) which allows you to run the swag container behind your VPN*

4. You will find your SSL certificates in the /config/etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourdomain}.duckdns.org folder of the SWAG container. Use those for the website/service that is running behind your forwarded port.

The certificates will get updated automatically 30 days before they expire. There is also a PKCS#12-file privkey.pfx, which is needed for services like emby. For more information on SWAG see the [LinuxServer.io Docs](https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag). You may or may not need another container running that updates the Duck DNS IP periodically, I'm not sure if the SWAG container already does that.

All of this can of course be done without Docker and with your own domain. In this case you will need to map your domain or subdomain to the VPN IP in the DNS Record section of your domain provider. And then use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to create certificates for that domain. Docker just automates the renewal part.